# Play Services 8.3.0 crashing - Android 4.4.4

Tags: google-play-services

I've PAC rom with Android 4.4.4 on my n7 (2013) and sgs3 and everything is working fine.

Google Play Services on version 8.3 crashs all the time. 8.1.15.x is working fine.

Are there any solutions?

Clearing data of GPS (not the location service) didn't help: services and store.

Can I disable auto update of services?

It is really annoying to downgrade it with Titanium Backup all the time. *(The crash messages are not better)*

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is custom rom, so first chect the theme of that rom if you found it on the forum, maybe it is a known bug for rom. And maybe, just maybe you flashed the wrong gapps package, did you tried flashing another package of gapps for that rom?

Comment: nope | it is the newest 4.4.4 pa gapps

Comment: Than you can try to stop updating services this way: search on google 'google play services', than open it with play store, and there press menu key, or if you donct have it pres on 3 dots in top right corner, there you should have option auto update, just uncheck it. Of corse you have first to downgrade services..

Comment: Whoops my bad, there isn't option to turn off auto update for play services. Only you can try different gapps package, maybe it will help